# Find difference between object & timedate fields in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe "df_OUT" as below. I am using python 2.7  -

```
>>> df_OUT.dtypes
TRX_DATE              datetime64[ns]
ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED            object
```

The values in the dataframe looks like below -

```
>>> df_OUT.head(5)
    TRX_DATE   ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED
0 1995-09-08  4712-12-31 00:00:00
2 2003-06-30  4712-12-31 00:00:00
3 2003-06-30  4712-12-31 00:00:00
4 2003-06-30  4712-12-31 00:00:00
6 1999-08-31  2099-08-31 00:00:00
```

Now I want to find the difference between "TRX_DATE" & "ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED            " in numerals with & without the days part.

I tried the below -

```
df_FINAL_RESULTS['TRX_DATE']-df_FINAL_RESULTS['ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Which gave me the error -

```
TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation
```

Can you please guide me on the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Your datetime strings cannot be parsed by pandas or by datetime.strptime are these valid datetime strings?

Comment: I have the solution - df_FINAL_RESULTS['TRX_DATE'].astype(datetime) - df_FINAL_RESULTS['ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED'].astype(datetime). Worked for me thanks.

Comment: You noticed that the ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED year is 4712 & 2099?

Comment: @Alexander - Yes, I am aware that the dataset has dummy data here.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the pandas Timestamp has a maximum date in the year 2261. We will need to use the python datetime.date construct.

```
# this is not nice data - well past pandas.Timestamp.max
# let's get it as strings into a pandas DataFrame
data = """index, TRX_DATE,   ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED
0,   1995-09-08,  4712-12-31 00:00:00
2,   2003-06-30,  4712-12-31 00:00:00
3,   2003-06-30,  4712-12-31 00:00:00
4,   2003-06-30,  4712-12-31 00:00:00
6,   1999-08-31,  2099-08-31 00:00:00
"""
from StringIO import StringIO # import from io for Python 3
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0, sep=',', index_col=0, 
    skipinitialspace=True, dtype={'ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED': object})

# convert to python datetime.date - will do in new columns
import datetime as dt
df['closed'] = [dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ).date() 
    for x in df['ACTUAL_DATE_CLOSED']]
df['transaction'] = [dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d', ).date() 
    for x in df['TRX_DATE']]

# find the difference between the two dates
df['difference'] = df['closed'] - df['transaction']
```